# Optmizing video for rtmp streaming?

Tags: video, streaming, rtmp, bitrate

Does anyone know of a guide of how to best optimize video for streaming (RTMP) over the internet? Including optimisation of:

- bitrate
- framerate
- frame size
- audio
- p vs i frame proportions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any clear answer here for each of the items you've listed, but this may help overall.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29231&seqNum=5
A flash professional named Lisa Larson-Kelly is an expert in this field and doing a google search including her name may give you what you need.